# "are added" -or- "are being added"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Basically, what I want to say is: "new pictures are constantly added", but I need to omit "constantly", so how would be grammatically correct to say this phrase meaning `constantly`: "new pictures are added" -or- "new pictures are being added"?

Comment: neither means exactly "new pictures are constantly added" - if you need to say constantly you have to say constantly (or continually/repeatedly etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> New pictures are regularly added.